# ubuntu 18.04: impossible to connect wifi Qualcomm Atheros AR9485

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I hope I am not doing any duplicate but it has been many hours that I have been trying everything to solve my problem but nothing works. 
This morning my wifi connection was working well, then I install the last update for Ubuntu and when I rebooted my laptop the wifi was not working. I want to point out that the wifi networks are detected but with very low signal that makes unable my laptop to connect. Here is some information

```
$ lspci | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3402 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo lshw -class network
*-network                 
   description: Interface réseau sans fil
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial number: 40:e2:30:d2:c9:fd
   bits: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   fonctionnality: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-45-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   ressources: irq:18 mémoire:f7900000-f797ffff mémoire:f7980000-f798ffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
   logical name: eth0
   version: 12
   serial: 08:62:66:b6:70:0e
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   bits: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   fonctionnality: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:f7814000-f7814fff mémoire:f7810000-f7813fff

$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"freebox_JTIXDN"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:24:D4:D1:3B:04   
      Bit Rate=2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:88  Invalid misc:449   Missed beacon:0

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

If youd need more information please let me know! I am really desesperate...

Thank you very much

Comment: which driver is in use?

Comment: Hi. I am using ath9k.